# Get real-time output from exe using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file for capturing application events - PresentMon (https://github.com/GameTechDev/PresentMon).
What I want to do is quite simple - use it to find out the current fps of the game-application. When it with the help of python (using subprocess) I can not get its output.
After a bit of research I found out that it has a parameter -output_stdout which allows me to get output like this

Terraria.exe,8500,0x0000000021BED180,D3D9,-1,0,0,0.03993460000000,0.65010000000000,22.59590000000000,0,Composed: Copy with GPU GDI,3.355900000000000000,12.053500000000000000,20.86110000000000

(Application,ProcessID,SwapChainAddress,Runtime,SyncInterval,PresentFlags,Dropped,TimeInSeconds,msInPresentAPI,msBetweenPresents,AllowsTearing,PresentMode,msUntilRenderComplete,msUntilDisplayed,msBetweenDisplayChange)

I have tried to get fps with msBetweenPresents , but it often shows what I believe is not very accurate.
You can run PresentMon just then you can get this realtime output which is changed with /r

Terraria.exe[20784]: 0000000020E5B440 (D3D9): SyncInterval=-1 Flags=0 CPU/Display=22.02/21.22ms (45.4/47.1 fps) latency=28.99ms Composed: Copy with GPU GDI ** RECORDING **

And as I looked here the fps value is quite true, but the problem is that I can't get the output.

Trying different things, I tried this code

```
import subprocess
import time


def stop_PresentMon():
    subprocess.Popen(['PresentMon64.exe', '-terminate_existing'])


def start_presentmon(pid):
    command = ['PresentMon64.exe', '-process_id', str(pid)]
    p = subprocess.Popen(command, creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    while True:
        print(p.stdout.read().decode().strip())
        time.sleep(0.1)


pid = 12512
stop_PresentMon()
start_presentmon(pid)
```

zero output, pressed ctrl+c twice on the new window (the window closed expectantly) and got

Started recording.
Stopped recording.

Nothing further
That didn't sit well with me for two reasons:
1 - zero results
2 - the output appeared only after closing PresentMon

Finally I'm trying to get this output in real time using python.

Comment: The issue is probably buffering.  When an application writes to stdout and stdout is a terminal, the output gets flushed.  When the output is not to a terminal, the writes are kept in a buffer until the buffer exceeds some size, like 4k bytes.  Since you have the source code, you should be able to change the output to "unbuffered", or force a flush after each write.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like they are doing direct calls to the Windows Console APIs.  That's a full-screen technique that makes for cool displays but is impossible to capture.  I'm not sure there is a good solution here, without some major rework to the `Console.cpp` code.

Comment: @TimRoberts I haven't studied C++, so I'd like to see what needs to be changed, and then compile a new exe with those changes?

Comment: You can TRY adding `vprintf( format, args); fflush(stdout);` just after the `vsnprintf` in `vConsolePrint`.  That might double the output if you're running it at a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I have just tested it with ls. It reads the stdout until there are no more bytes and prints it right away.

```
p=subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-R'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline,b''):
    print(line)
```